# Is it possible to open a webpage in an AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, webview, web, android-alertdialog

I want to open a web site within a Alert Dialog, but I have no idea how to do this. Any tips to get this to work? 
The alert dialog should take the user to the webpage within the alertdialog itsself

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open up an Alert Dialog with a webview, as far as I know.  But what you can do is create a WebView activity and put it in your manifest that the Theme="XXXX/XXX.Dialog".  This will make it look like a dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to open a webpage in alert dialog.  Instead, you could use modal window to open up a web site.